# Showing dates in Year,Qtr format in Acumatica Generic Inquiries

Tags: erp, acumatica

In Acumatica Cloud ERP, How can I create a calculated column that shows a date field formatted as Year, Quarter.  i.e.   Dec 21, 2014  to show "2014, Q4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your Generic Inquiry, just add a field to your field list use the expression editor in the “Data Field”  and put in something like below.   In this example I am formatting the Invoice Date field (ARInvoice.DocDate),  so replace this with the date field you want to format.

```
=CStr(Year([ARInvoice.DocDate]))+', Q'+
CStr(Switch( month([ARInvoice.DocDate])>0 and month([ARInvoice.DocDate])<4,1,
         month([ARInvoice.DocDate]) >3 and month([ARInvoice.DocDate])<7,2 ,
         month([ARInvoice.DocDate])>6 and month([ARInvoice.DocDate])<10,3,1=1,4))
```